# MS Word VBA code to align image to top right corner

Tags: vba, ms-word

I was trying to write a VBA macro to align an image to the top right corner of the page and set text wrapping to "Behind Text" and "Fixed Position on Page."

Normally I select the image and do all those settings through dialog boxes. But it gets tedious after a while. I'm wondering if there's a way to do it programmatically. I'm hoping I could open the page header, paste in my header image, and then click a macro button to have the macro align the still-selected image.

I tried recording a macro of my operations, but the macro did not record any of my dialog actions (behind text, fixed page position, etc).  So that method provided no solution. I tried it with images inside and outside of page headers, without success.

Is it possible to have some VBA code align the currently selected image object? Ideally, I would open up the page header, paste in my header image, and run a VBA macro to do the four operations above (behind text, fixed position on page, align top to page, align right side to page). I'm hoping someone can show me how or point me to some documentation or examples that show how to do it.

UPDATE

I couldn't post to the forum for some reason, so I worked on the problem for a couple of days and finally pieced together this solution for the next person. I wish I knew where to look in a manual or tutorial for this kind of thing.

But the only way seems to be to cobble solutions together from forums on the net. Here's my contribution! :-)

```
Sub AlignTopRight()
' Paste an image into Word so it is still selected
' Then invoke this macro to align it to the top right corner
' And to set it behind text, fixed position on the page

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Shp As Shape
On Error Resume Next
    'I'm not sure if this block is required, but it works
     Set Shp = Selection.InlineShapes(1)
     If Not Shp Is Nothing Then
          Set Shp = Selection.InlineShapes(1).ConvertToShape
     Else
          Set Shp = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
     End If

    If Not Shp Is Nothing Then
    With Shp
      .LockAspectRatio = True
      ' for absolute positioning
      '.Left = CentimetersToPoints(5.5)
      '.Top = CentimetersToPoints(0.5)
      '.Width = CentimetersToPoints(2.5)
      'put the image behind text
      .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind
      'this was the tricky part, discovering this
      .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
      .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
      .Top = wdShapeTop 'if you say =0, it sets the AbsolutePx in the dialog
      .Left = wdShapeRight 'these wdShapeXX objects set the Align field in the dialog
    End With
    End If
Set Shp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered this feature to answer my own question. See the answer in the question posting.